# Why is there a periodical pattern of train loss for label recognition in supervised learning implemented in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, supervised-learning, loss

I met with a weird periodical pattern for train loss in a label classification problem using AdamOptimzer in tensorflow.

As shown in the image, train loss increased slightly with a sudden drop in every epoch. What is the possible reason of this?

[image: train loss]

`AdamOptimizer` is used with a warm-up+polynomial decay learning rate.

```py
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=0.00001)
train_op = opt.optimize(cross_entropy_loss, lr)
```

Data pipeline is described below.

```py
# data pipeline
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(tfrecords_names)

# shuffle filenames
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=config.num_parallel_readers)

# repeat filename lists
dataset = dataset.repeat(config.epoch)

dataset = dataset.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
                                cycle_length=config.num_parallel_readers)

# parse samples
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=parse_record,
                        num_parallel_calls=config.num_parallel_calls)

# prefetch samples
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=config.prefetch_buffer_size)

# shuffle samples
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=config.shuffle_buffer_size)

# make a batch
dataset = dataset.batch(config.batch_size)
```

Comment: Normally this would point to data not being shuffled properly. How big is your shuffle buffer? Can you verify that your data is being shuffled correctly, i.e. make sure it's not the same every epoch?

Comment: @xdurch0, I have 1000+ tfrecords with 10000 elements inside (each element is temproally related to its successive element). reader_num = 32, shuffle_buffer_size = 50000. Train batch_size = 1024. So this case is probably due to the temporal related samples in shuffle buffer, which does not consume all elements in a tfrecord. (32*10000 < 50000)